# Randomly getting "ORA-22814: attribute or element value is larger than specified in type" with a bulk collect into

Tags: oracle, plsql, user-defined-types

I have code that is randomly getting `"ORA-22814: attribute or element value is larger than specified in type"` with a bulk collect into.

I suspect this is a data issue since it's random but PL/SQL is not my strong suit but I maintain an application that has a great deal of it in processing logic.

This is an Oracle 12c database.

Any help would be appreciated!

This is the block of code:

```
  SELECT mxpv_activityupdate_O (
        projectid,
        task_id,
        task_code,
        pvtask_code,
        task_name,
        CASE
           WHEN wbs_t0_id IS NOT NULL AND scgemergent_flag = 'Y'
           THEN
              wbs_t0_id
           ELSE
              wbs_pv_id
        END,
        act_start_date,
        CASE
           WHEN act_end_date IS NOT NULL AND (invalidactfinish_flag = 'Y')
           THEN
              NULL
           ELSE
              act_end_date
        END,
        NULL,
        CASE WHEN invalidactuals_flag = 'Y' THEN NULL ELSE act_work_qty END,
        MAX (oid),
        scgemergent_flag,
        invalidactuals_flag,
        invalidactfinish_flag)
BULK COLLECT INTO u_all_tab
FROM (SELECT projectorganization,
             projecttype,
             projectid,
             task_id,
             task_code,
             pvtask_code,
             pvact_start_date,
             task_name,
             act_start_date,
             act_end_date,
             CASE
                WHEN     pvact_start_date IS NULL
                     AND act_start_date IS NULL
                     AND NVL (act_work_qty, 0) <> 0
                THEN
                   'Y'
                ELSE
                   'N'
             END
                invalidactuals_flag,
             act_work_qty,
             oid,
             wbs_t0_id,
             wbs_pv_id,
             CASE
                WHEN     pvact_start_date IS NULL
                     AND (act_start_date IS NOT NULL --or nvl(act_work_qty,0)<>0
                                                    )
                     AND projectorganization = 'SCG'
                     AND projecttype = 'Daily'
                     AND pvtarget_start_date > v_t0_start_midnight + 7
                THEN
                   'Y'
                ELSE
                   'N'
             END
                scgemergent_flag,
             CASE
                WHEN     act_end_date IS NOT NULL
                     AND NVL (act_start_date, pvact_start_date) IS NOT NULL
                     AND act_end_date <
                            NVL (act_start_date, pvact_start_date)
                THEN
                   'Y'
                ELSE
                   'N'
             END
                invalidactfinish_flag
        FROM (SELECT oid,
                     projecttype,
                     wbs_t0.wbs_id wbs_t0_id,
                     --emergentwork,
                     projectorganization,
                     projectid,
                     task_id,
                     pvwbs_id wbs_pv_id,
                     activityid task_code,
                     task_code pvtask_code,
                     pvact_start_date,
                     pvtarget_start_date,
                     CASE
                        WHEN pvact_end_date IS NULL THEN activityname
                        ELSE NULL
                     END
                        task_name,
                     CASE
                        WHEN     actualstart IS NOT NULL
                             AND (   pvact_start_date IS NULL
                                  OR actualfinish IS NOT NULL)
                        THEN
                           actualstart
                        ELSE
                           NULL
                     END
                        act_start_date,
                     --actualstart act_start_date,
                     CASE
                        WHEN     pvact_end_date IS NULL
                             AND (   pvact_start_date IS NOT NULL
                                  OR actualstart IS NOT NULL)
                        THEN
                           actualfinish
                        ELSE
                           NULL
                     END
                        act_end_date,
                     NULL target_start_date,
                     CASE WHEN mxactualunits.proj_catg_short_name = 'Y' --and nvl(pvact_work_qty, 0) <> nvl(actuallaborhours,0)
                     THEN NVL (actuallaborhours, 0) ELSE NULL END
                        act_work_qty
                FROM --1) activityid and proj id matches
                     (SELECT oid,
                             pv.task_id,
                             mx.proj_id,
                             mx.projectid,
                             pv.task_code,
                             pv.task_name,
                             pv.wbs_id pvwbs_id,
                             pv.act_start_date pvact_start_date,
                             pv.act_end_date pvact_end_date,
                             pv.target_start_date pvtarget_start_date,
                             mx.activityid,
                             mx.activityname,
                             mx.actualstart,
                             mx.actualfinish,
                             pv.act_work_qty pvact_work_qty,
                             mx.actuallaborhours,
                             mx.projectorganization,
                             mx.projecttype,
                             mx.process_start_ts                       --,
                        FROM mxpv_activity_tmp mx, mxpv_task_tmp pv
                       WHERE mx.task_id = pv.task_id
                      UNION
                      --3) PM Number/Job Plan number matches
                      SELECT oid,
                             jp.task_id,
                             jp.proj_id,
                             jp.proj_short_name,
                             jp.task_code,
                             jp.task_name,
                             jp.wbs_id,
                             jp.act_start_date pvtarget_start_date,
                             jp.act_end_date pvtarget_end_date,
                             jp.target_start_date pvtarget_start_date,
                             jp.activityid,
                             jp.activityname,
                             jp.actualstart,
                             jp.actualfinish,
                             jp.act_work_qty pvact_work_qty,
                             actuallaborhours,
                             projectorganization,
                             projecttype,
                             p_process_start_ts                        --,
                        FROM --3a) PM Number matches
                             (SELECT * FROM TABLE (pm_tab)
                              UNION
                              --3a) Job Plan Number matches
                              SELECT * FROM TABLE (jp_tab)) jp)
                     update_activity,
                     (SELECT projpcat.PROJ_ID, pcval.PROJ_CATG_SHORT_NAME
                        FROM privuser_PROJPCAT projpcat,
                             privuser_PCATTYPE pctype,
                             privuser_PCATVAL pcval
                       WHERE     projpcat.PROJ_CATG_ID = pcval.PROJ_CATG_ID
                             AND pcval.PROJ_CATG_TYPE_ID =
                                    pctype.PROJ_CATG_TYPE_ID
                             AND pctype.PROJ_CATG_TYPE = 'MX Actual Units')
                     mxactualunits,
                     (SELECT w.wbs_id, w.proj_id
                        FROM privuser_projwbs w, privuser_phase ph
                       WHERE     w.phase_id = ph.phase_id
                             AND ph.phase_name = '0') wbs_t0
               WHERE     --update_activity.proj_id = actstrtoffset.proj_id (+)
                         update_activity.proj_id = wbs_t0.proj_id(+)
                     AND update_activity.proj_id = mxactualunits.proj_id(+)
                     AND update_activity.process_start_ts =
                            p_process_start_ts--and delete_ts is null
             ))
GROUP BY projectid,
         task_id,
         task_code,
         pvtask_code,
         task_name,
         wbs_t0_id,
         wbs_pv_id,
         act_start_date,
         act_end_date,
         act_work_qty,
         invalidactuals_flag,
         invalidactfinish_flag,
         scgemergent_flag,
         pvact_start_date;
```

The type is defined as follows:

```
TYPE PV_APP_DATA.MXPV_ACTIVITYUPDATE_O AS OBJECT(


proj_short_name VARCHAR2 (100),
         task_id NUMBER,
         task_code VARCHAR2 (120 CHAR),
         pvtask_code VARCHAR2 (120 CHAR),
         task_name VARCHAR2 (120 CHAR),
         wbs_id NUMBER,
         act_start_date DATE,
         act_end_date DATE,
         target_start_date DATE,
         act_work_qty NUMBER,
         oid NUMBER,
         scgemergent_flag VARCHAR2 (10),
         invalidactuals_flag VARCHAR2 (100),
         invalidactfinish_flag VARCHAR2 (100)

)
```

Please post if you need more information I wasn't sure what could be useful.

update 1 7/18/17 
I modified the query with substr with no luck in fixing the problem:

```
select mxpv_activityupdate_O(
substr(projectid,0,99),
task_id,
substr(task_code,0,119),
substr(pvtask_code,0,119),
substr(task_name,0,119),
case when wbs_t0_id is not null and   scgemergent_flag='Y' then wbs_t0_id
  else wbs_pv_id end,
act_start_date,
case when act_end_date is not null and
  (invalidactfinish_flag='Y'
  )
  then null else act_end_date end,
null,
case when invalidactuals_flag = 'Y' then null else act_work_qty end,
max(oid),
substr(scgemergent_flag,0,9),
substr(invalidactuals_flag,0,99),
substr(invalidactfinish_flag,0,99)
)
bulk collect into u_all_tab
from
(SELECT
projectorganization,
projecttype,
  substr(projectid,0,99) as projectid,
  task_id,
  substr(task_code,0,119) as task_code,
  substr(pvtask_code,0,119) as pvtask_code,
  pvact_start_date,
  substr(task_name,0,119) as task_name,
  act_start_date,
  act_end_date,
    case when pvact_start_date is null and act_start_date is null
    and nvl(act_work_qty, 0) <> 0 then 'Y' else 'N' end invalidactuals_flag,
act_work_qty,
  oid,
  wbs_t0_id,
  wbs_pv_id,
    case when pvact_start_date is null and
    (act_start_date is not null --or nvl(act_work_qty,0)<>0
    )
    and projectorganization='SCG' and projecttype='Daily'
    and pvtarget_start_date>v_t0_start_midnight+7
    then 'Y' else 'N' end scgemergent_flag,
    case when act_end_date is not null and nvl(act_start_date, pvact_start_date) is not null
      and act_end_date<nvl(act_start_date, pvact_start_date) then 'Y' else 'N' end
      invalidactfinish_flag
  FROM
```

Comment: Probably you have strings longer than the defined on the object.

Comment: One way to trouble shoot this is to convert the select statement into a CTAS  (remove "BULK COLLECT INTO u_all_tab", add 'create table as deleteme_table" at beginning). Run the statement and compare the column types of the created table with MXPV_ACTIVITYUPDATE_O .

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza if I want to force to correct length what's the best approach?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza  
I updated the post. I added SUBSTR() to two parts of the query but when I ran it I still got the error?

Comment: @russell1997 Is hard to guess what is the column giving you problems, my suggestion is remove one column each time  until you find the culprit or change the size max of your object to something like 4000

Comment: OT: I got same error in expression `cast(collect(some_number38_column) as some_nested_table_of_number)`. Correcting `some_number38_column` to `to_number(some_number38_column)` helped. Probably it is some issue in conversion of collection internals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "if I want to force to correct length what's the best approach?"

You need to compare the length of the Tables' columns with the length of the Type's target attributes, and see which attributes are shorter than the columns you're trying to fit into them. Use the data dictionary.

For the Type Attributes use [USER_TYPE_ATTRS](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/statviews_2109.htm#i1592720) (or ALL_TYPE_ATTRS if it's a different schema):

```
select attribute_name, attr_type_name, length, scale, precision
from user_type_attrs
where type_name = 'MXPV_ACTIVITY_UPDATE_O'
/
```

For the Table Columns it will be a similar query based on [USER_TAB_COLS](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/statviews_2090.htm#REFRN20276).

Once you have established the errant columns you will need to alter the type to enlarge the attributes. Alternatively apply `SUBSTR()` function to the columns in the query projection, to cut them down to size. Which is actually better depends on the circumstances of your application, although usually we would prefer the approach which doesn't lose data.

Comment: I updated the post. I added SUBSTR() to two parts of the query but when I ran it I still got the error?

Comment: column data types of global temporary table and type are same. Still facing this issue. Tried SUBSTR() still it does not help. @APC I am using PIVOT query